# Ideal dimensions of a ninepatch background

Tags: android, android-layout, nine-patch

I want to create a ninepatch background file (the background is a gradient image). I would like to know what are the ideal dimensions of the background image?

In addition to that, where should I put the image: `drawable-ldpi`, `drawable-mdpi` or `drawable-hdpi`?

Comment: For example if I create a background image of 60px x 60px where do i put the image?

Comment: make it as small as possible, and put it in drawable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your SDK folder inside: `/platforms/android-X/data/res/drawable-hdpi`
You will notice there are a bunch of 9patches there. I understand that you should provide a 9patch for each type of device. So you should have a 9patch for `ldpi`, one for `mdpi` and one for `hdpi`.
The idea is to make it as small as possible and also take into account that the 9patch doesn't go smaller than the original.

On the other hand, I don't think that a 9patch will be useful when dealing with gradient images.
I would try using a [GradientDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/GradientDrawable.html).

Answer (score 0):

I think its 40dip x 40dip or 60px x 60px.